# Fast access to shared folder

Tags: speed, far-manager

Very often I need to access shared folder in another PC using Far Manager.

To go via ALT+F1>>network takes too long, because it scans whole network. What is the faster way of doing that?

Answer (score 9):

If you are talking about quick access to *any* shared resource on a *particular* PC, then [@icabod's](https://superuser.com/a/521543/68239) is probably the best suggestion there is at this point.

If, however, you mean you want to access a *particular resource* quickly, there are more options for you.

1. You can still go with @icabod's suggestion of using the `net:` command, you'd just need to append the resource to the path:

   ```
   net:\\matespc\resource
   ```
2. You can use the `cd` command:

   ```
   cd \\matespc\resource
   ```
3. You can use the Folder Shortcuts functionality.

   Basically, you first assign a folder shortcut using a specific key combination, then you can *always* change to that folder very quickly using another keyboard shortcut. There are ten assignment shortcuts and ten corresponding navigation shortcuts:

   Assignment           Navigation
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> — <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> — <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> — <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> — <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> — <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> — <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> — <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> — <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> — <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> — <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>

   There's also a dialog box to manage the list of assigned folder shortcuts (<kbd>F9</kbd> → `Commands` → `Folder shortcuts`, or <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>).

Answer (score 7):

If you know the IP or hostname of the PC that you wish to access, you can use the `net:` command in FAR Manager (you'll need the `Network Browser` plugin, which probably comes by default depending on which version you're using).

For example, if the hostname of the PC is `matespc` you can enter the following on the command line:

```
net:\\matespc
```

This will open up a network panel directly pointing to that PC.

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the party, but of course another alternative is to mount the network share to a local drive...

```
net use Q: \\matespc\resource
```

...and selecting it via the standard drive selector <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> respectively.